# Are grenades thrown further when jumping?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

Once a friend told me that in Call of Duty... If you jump/or right after the jump when you're in the air moving upwards and then throw a grenade (for example a Semtex) - that the distance will be much further than throwing just from the stand/run (normal)

Since then I do that always and I also see people online doing that.. but is that true?

Answer (score 4):

Jumping in CoD **does** add to the inertia of a grenade. With good timing and aim, you can achieve much greater throw distances.

Just make sure you don't lob too high, or it will obviously timeout in midair

Comment: any evidences and/or sources?

Comment: it may sound sad, but me and friend were actually testing this awhile ago using throwing knives across maps. foolish as we were, we did not record and document our findings... we truly are a failure to science :(

Comment: It is easiest to see when using C4 or a Bouncing Betty in Black Ops 2. Throw it from a standing position and then again whilst jumping on the spot.

Comment: yes. Even throwing whilst walking forward or back makes a great difference.

Comment: is this in "every" CoD like that?

Comment: hard to answer that without having them to test but i assume all past CoD 4 at the very least